# How to set FreeSwitch and STUN/TURN when using resiprocate?

Tags: webrtc, sip, freeswitch, stun, turn

I m going to build webrtc android client with my kamilio/freeswitch.

I m using resiprocate for p2p connection between clients.

How can I set freeswitch and TURN server when using resiprocate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The turn server is independent of the sip server. You don't have to setup anything about TURN on freeswitch. You just have to set your turn server address for your webrtc client.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.